# potrait image is not displaying correct in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
class News(models.Model):

    news_heading = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    news_date = models.DateTimeField()
    news_details = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    image_one = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/news",blank=True)
    image_one_height = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True,default=300)
    image_one_width = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True,default=300)

    image_two = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/news",blank=True)
    image_two_height = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True,default=300)
    image_two_width = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True,default=300)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.news_heading
```

**This is my model.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import News
# Create your views here.

def news_view(request):
    news = News.objects.order_by('-id')
    context = {
        'news':news
    }
    return render(request,'news/news.html',context)
```

*This is my view.py  what should i have to do to make image display correct.
Potrait images are displaying rotated left. how to make them display correct.*

```
{% extends "homepage/navbar.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
       <style type="text/css">
            img {
                image-orientation: from-image;
            }
        </style>
<section class="mbr-section content5 cid-rjuc1r5LAi" id="content5-w">





    <div class="container">
        <div class="media-container-row">
            <div class="title col-12 col-md-8">
                <h2 class="align-center mbr-bold mbr-white pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-2"><span style="font-weight: normal;">
                    NEWS & UPDATES
                </span></h2>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row"> 
            {% for update in news %}
            <dir class="col-md-10" style="border-left: 2px solid red; border-bottom: 2px solid #3e4095">
                <h2>{{ update.news_heading }}</h2>

                {% if update.image_one %}
                    <img src="{{ update.image_one.url }}" width="{{update.image_one_width}}" height="{{update.image_one_height}}">
                {% endif %}
                {% if update.image_two %}
                    <img src="{{ update.image_two.url }}" width="{{update.image_two_width}}" height="{{update.image_two_height}}">
                {% endif %}

                <p>{{ update.news_details }}</p>
            </dir>
            {% endfor %}
        </div> 

    </div>


</section>
{% endblock %}
```

This is template code.

what should i have to do to make image display correct.
Potrait images are displaying rotated left. how to make them display correct.

Comment: please share your template code

Comment: "Potrait images are displaying rotated left" => looks like an exif issue. Is this always the case whatever image you test with ? (nb you have to use images from various sources to make sure). Do you have the issue with all browsers or just with your own ?

Comment: Also note that with your current model definition, your "image_x_height" and "image_x_witdh" fields won't be automagically populated from the image's data. You have to explicitely tell the `image_field` where to store those info, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#imagefield

Comment: @ bruno desthuilliers not an issue with all Potrait images. But only some.